# Emulator doesn't start because of missing Vulkan, but Vulkan is installed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to start my emulator, but I get this message:

```
2023-03-08 10:35:22,742 [1953359]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
2023-03-08 10:35:22,768 [1953385]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file /home/bf/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_30.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-03-08 10:35:22,863 [1953480]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 30 - cannot add library /home/bf/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
```

Vulkan drivers seem to be installed, and all Android tools are upgraded (the emulator I have reinstalled completely):

```
Package mesa-vulkan-drivers-22.3.6-1.fc37.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I am using Fedora 37.

I read that from API30 it uses Vulkan, but running a lower API gives the same error. I tried to change the Emulated Performance as well (found that tip online), but I cannot change that:

[image]

It is getting a little frustrating that a simple thing like this doesn't work (anymore), so any help is appreciated, even workarounds. I just want to run a few small tests on my Android app.

Note: the emulator does start, it just doesn't show anything in the window:

```
[bf@localhost platform-tools]$ ps ax | grep qemu
  25331 pts/3    Sl+    0:00 /home/bf/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_2_API_30 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I also had VirtualBox running a Windows guest, which conflicts with the Android emulator.

No solution on how to fix this though.